# How to inherit from a class with a protected data type?

Tags: delphi, inheritance, protected

I have a base generics class with an inner protected class. How do I inherit from the base class and access the protected inner class?

As an example this code will not compile:

```
unit uFoo;

interface

type

  TFoo<T> = class
  protected
    type
      TFooProtected = class

      end;
  end;

  TFoo2<T> = class(TFoo<T>)
  protected
    item: TFooProtected;
  end;
```

Comment: You will need to fully qualify the type :`item: TFoo<T>.TFooPrivate;`

Comment: And the question has nothing to do with generics per se. It is valid for any class where the type is declared internally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
type
  TFoo<T> = class
  protected
    type
      TFooProtected = class
      end;
  end;

  TFoo2<T> = class(TFoo<T>)
  protected
    item: TFoo<T>.TFooProtected;
  end;
```

Note that this has nothing to do with generics.  It is valid for any class where the type is declared internally.